# Does nuxt js have place to run at the beginning of the project

Tags: nuxt.js

I have some codes need to run at the beginning of the project, and it will be used in each page. Right now I have to copy those codes every time in each pages. So I am wondering what's the easier way to do that?

Comment: It depends on where your code should be run, SSR or front. "at the beginning of the projet" and "used in each page" is not clear. You should add the code you've attempted to run as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question.

Comment: «Don't repeat yourself» is definitely something you want to do. As @ManUtopiK said, it is important to knoy what «at the beginning of your project» means. What does the code do?
You could either run it on `nuxtServerInit`, run it in your layout template (which is maybe used on all your pages, if you just have one layout) on `mounted()` if you need the DOM to be loaded.. etc.
Another way is to extend a component, which executes a method on `mounted` and `extend` it on every page you need the code to run.
But, just tell us more, and we can tell you more... :)